# How to Change Table Validation Error Message in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a set of fairly complicated table validation rules that I'm using to keep my data clean in one of my MS Access tables. The rules appear to be working well, but when a rule is violated it generates a nasty-looking error message. The whole string of rules comes up in the message - not exactly user-friendly.

I've tried to replace the message using code similar to this in the form's `OnError` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
  If DataErr = 2601 Then
    MsgBox ("Case Number already entered")
    Response = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

However, apparently I haven't managed to find the correct error number because the If statement never fires. I checked here, but apparently it's not 3317 or 4001.

Also, when I removed the If statement and just had the MsgBox fire on any error, the standard error came up along with the message box - it's not being replaced.

Any idea how to address these issues?

Comment: I suggest you make use of the `Err` object in the event `Form_BeforeUpdate()`. You may find it much easier to trouble shoot and exploit.

Comment: You should probably explain that you can't just set the corresponding Validation Text property for each Validation Rule.  Otherwise, someone is bound to suggest that as the obvious simple solution.

Comment: Haha - well, being an Access newbie I wasn't aware of the validation text functionality. Looks like that'll do it - thanks!