# Find error number for validation error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table where some fields have a validation rule set, and a validation message. 
Data entry is done in a form, and when the data validation rule is broken then the validation error message is displayed in a pop-up. All good so far.

However I then want to have the form text box or combobox for the field that is triggering the validation message be highlighted on the form e.g. with a different background colour.

I assumed I would need to do this in the On Error procedure for the form, and specify the error number. But I have no idea how to find the error number? E.g. this method: [How to Change Table Validation Error Message in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876070/how-to-change-table-validation-error-message-in-ms-access)

Perhaps I am going about this completely the wrong way and instead of specifying the error messages in the table properties I should be setting up it up with VBA?

V grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction with this as I am still a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

The error number you seek is `7753` - this is returned by the `DataErr` (1st argument) of the event procedure for the `On Error` event.

However, I personally don't like using Validation Rules in Access, and prefer to test the validity of input through VBA as part of the data submission (i.e. when the user clicks on a control to submit their data)

For example, this approach is similar to web forms flagging invalid fields when the form is submitted, as opposed to locking a user into a particular field until valid data has been specified.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just not sure how to specify which field has caused the error if that makes sense? Because I would want the particular control bound to that field to be the one highlighted, and there is validation set up on a number of different fields. I take your point about doing this with VBA as part of the data submission of defining it at the table level, I already have a Before Update process that prompts users to save or cancel (undo) so I suppose I could set up the validation there.

Comment: It ended up being 3316. So I am using as the DataErr argument in the On Error event with further conditions depending on the field breaking the validation rule, and then SetFocus to the appropriate control. It's probably not perfect but it works for what I need.